# File name recorded in directory differs from database

Tags: php, mysql, file, upload

I have the following script that generates a random timestamp for my filename.

```
 $newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . ".jpg";
```

However, the filename that is uploaded to my mySQL database is different from the one recorded in my directory, which causes the image to fail to display.

For example, on one occasion, the image in the database is recorded as **1441743610.jpg**, while the image in the directory is **1441743609.jpg**.

This is my code:

```
session_start();

$username = $_SESSION['username'];

$file_dir = "userpictures/$username" ;

mkdir($file_dir, 0777, true);

// $_FILES["file"]["name'] is the file that is uploaded by her

$filePath = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$image = imagecreatefrompng($filePath);
$bg = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($image), imagesy($image));
imagefill($bg, 0, 0, imagecolorallocate($bg, 255, 255, 255));
imagealphablending($bg, TRUE);
imagecopy($bg, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($image), imagesy($image));
imagedestroy($image);
$quality = 100; // 0 = worst / smaller file, 100 = better / bigger file 
imagejpeg($bg, $filePath . ".jpg", $quality);
imagedestroy($bg);

// this chunk here converts the file to jpg


$newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . ".jpg";
// round(microtime) generates a randomized number.


// check format of image before uploading
$imageFileType = pathinfo($newfilename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" &&   $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) 

{
echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}

else

{
$uploadOk = 1;
}


// if any errors have occured (determined by $uploadOk), the critical "move_uploaded_files" php function is not activated

if ($uploadOk == 1) 

{
$filename = $newfilename;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "user_pictures/$username/" . $filename);
}
```

Would appreciate advise on why this is happening. Note that this behaviour is not consistent and it *works most of the time.*, but thats not acceptable to me.

EDIT:

This is the code where I upload the `$filename` to the database (as well as other data)

```
$con = mysqli_connect("FARM.mysql.anyhost.com", "user", "password");
  if (!$con) {
  die("Something went wrong. Don't worry, just refresh the page"); }

mysqli_select_db($con, "FARM");
  if (mysqli_select_db($con, "FARM") == false) {
  die("Something went wrong. Don't worry, just refresh the page"); }

$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$post = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['postdescription']);
$timestamp = date("jS \of F Y h:i:s A P");


$user_uploadposts = "INSERT INTO $username (PostingTime, Image, Description)  VALUES ('$timestamp','$filename', '$post')";


mysqli_query($con, $user_uploadposts);
mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your query is when saving the filepath in the database but according to the behaviour you're explaining here :

> Note that this behaviour is not consistent and it works most of the time., but thats not acceptable to me.

the problem is that you're not using $newfilename when saving to the database, but "recreating" the filename again with `$newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . ".jpg";`

This causes that in the meanwhile microtime is incrementing and the names are not equal anymore. The reason why it sometimes works is because the script goes sometimes faster through. To avoid this you just have to use $newfilename instead of creating the variable again.

h.u.

Comment: I decided to store $newfilename as a SESSION variable. This SESSION variable will then be called when inserting into the database, thus avoiding calling $newfilename twice (and generating the microtime again, as you've explained) Do you think this will resolve it? `else{ move_uploaded_file($_FILES["hello"]["tmp_name"], "user_pictures/$username/" . $newfilename); $_SESSION['filename'] = $newfilename;}`

Comment: Yes this would resolve the problem. But I don't think its a good idea to store it in the session, session are not made for this purpose.

Comment: or maybe just a variable again? so like `$thisfilename = $newfilename` But I'm wondering, if I call $thisfilename again, will it be calculating the value of $newfilename again, which will then equals to a new microtome, or will it only refer to the value of $newfilename at the time that it was created? Do you get what I'm saying?

Comment: Yes I get it. It would not calculate it again. It would just copy that value without calculating the time again.

Comment: It happened again. The file name differs even with this new method. What is peculiar is that every single time it happens the filenames differs by exactly 1. Comparing the filename saved in my directory vs that saved in the database:

`1441915093.jpg` | `1441915094.jpg`
`1441912835.jpg` | `1441912836.jpg` 
`1441912198.jpg` | `1441912199.jpg`

What do you think could be the problem again?

Comment: Could you maybe post the code where you store the filename in the database? Besides of that you don't need to use round(microtime()). Either just use time() or just use microtime(). time = round(microtime()).

Comment: And does the problem still remains? It should work like this.. Do you get any error ?

Comment: Yes, the problem still remains. I'm very puzzled myself.